# Insert innerHTML of all elements which have same class name to another element

Tags: javascript, html

I have some elements have same class name and i insert their innerHTML in another element have classname "show". Expected output is 12345 but it is only show last element's innerHTML(5). Here is my code snippet;

```js
 source = document.getElementsByClassName("source");
  show = document.getElementsByClassName("show");
for(var i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
 show[0].innerHTML =  source[i].innerHTML;
```

```css
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<span class="source">1</span>
<span class="source">2</span>
<span class="source">3</span>
<span class="source">4</span>
<span class="source">5</span>

<span class="show"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.reduce()` to concatenate the HTML to an accumulator for each element. `Array.from` simply allows you to use `.reduce()` on an array of DOM elements:

```js
var source = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("source"))
var show = document.getElementsByClassName("show")[0];

show.innerHTML = source.reduce((a, el) => a += el.innerHTML, '')
```

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="source">1</span>
<span class="source">2</span>
<span class="source">3</span>
<span class="source">4</span>
<span class="source">5</span>

<span class="show"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `+` for adding number `show[0].innerHTML +=  source[i].innerHTML;`

```js
source = document.getElementsByClassName("source");
show = document.getElementsByClassName("show");
debugger;
for(var i = 0; i < source.length; i++){
 show[0].innerHTML +=  source[i].innerHTML;
}
```

```css
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<span class="source">1</span>
<span class="source">2</span>
<span class="source">3</span>
<span class="source">4</span>
<span class="source">5</span>

<span class="show"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 source = document.getElementsByClassName("source");
  show = document.getElementsByClassName("show");
for(var i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
 show[0].innerHTML +=  source[i].innerHTML;
```

```css
.show{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<span class="source">1</span>
<span class="source">2</span>
<span class="source">3</span>
<span class="source">4</span>
<span class="source">5</span>

<span class="show"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `show[0].innerHTML +=  source[i].innerHTML;`